# Jira OR confluence automated task notification when coming up to due date

Tags: confluence, jql

I am working within confluences new automation tool with goal to create a automation to run weekly and identify tasks that are due within 2 months, and then send an email to task owner. How would you do this?

I have used the automation of trigger: scheduled; then: lookup pages; task branch: where status is incomplete and due date is coming up in 60 days; then: send email {{task.assignee.emailAddress}}.

I wanted a CQL (similar to JQL) to filter tasks with text "Page review due" but automation stated incompatible